# Nurturing creativity

Tags: development-methodologies

What is the best development methodology for nurturing personal creativity? Why do you think it's better than others?

The methodologies can be agile, traditional or whatever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best methodology for this is anything which

- **lets developers do their work** and solve problems the way they see best,
- leaves the choice (and responsibility) of technical decisions to the developers, and
- allows them to **deliver quality** *they* (and not only the clients/sponsors) are satisfied with,
- allows and encourages **communication** (both within and without the team),
- last but not least, **is accepted and followed by the team** because they are happy with and committed to it, not because of external dictate.

Usually agile methods are good at these (this is one of the reasons they came into being). But any methodology can be good or bad in its practical incarnation in a specific team and project. Any method(ology) needs to be tailored and fine-tuned for the needs of the team and project, during which it may change considerably. And we have all heard of shops loudly preaching "we do agile" when in reality their process is something completely different :-( So the issue is not how the method is labeled, but how it works in one's concrete team and project.

[Peopleware 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633439) discusses such issues in much greater detail - although they talk about *productivity* rather than *creativity*, I believe that in this context the two are fairly close so that the book's suggestions are useful here.

Comment: The important balance to strike is adding structure _where it helps_, and not mandate it where it hurts.  In other words the methodology supports your team, as opposed to the team supporting the methodology.

Comment: Sometimes the creative ideas come from non-developers. I'm not too sure developers at Apple have historically set higher standards than Steve Jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Any methodology that does not punish people when they are creative (And we all want to be creative.). 
Avoid:

1. Rigid time schedules (Does not mean limit amount of time on task)
2. discouraging programming on own time
3. limiting internet access, research, and SO site participation
4. Immediately trying to calculate ROI when you don't even know how to use the new feature.
5. Provide training/study in areas not specific to the programming language/framework currently being used. Who knows, you may learn something useful from chemistry.

And make sure everyone is aware of your current problems/issues with your users, company or business partners. I try to stress to people to give me problems and not ask me how to implement solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**One of these, is not like the other.**

### The definitions, themselves, are contradictory:

*Methodology*:

- a set or system of methods, principles, and rules for regulating a given discipline, as in the arts or sciences.

*Creativity*:

- the ability to transcend traditional ideas, rules, patterns, relationships, or the like, and to create meaningful new ideas, forms, methods, interpretations, etc.;*

Again, for clarity...

**Methodology: A set of rules for regulating a discipline.**

**Creativity: The ability to transcend traditional rules.**

By definition, the best "methodology" **for creativity** is [CowboyCoding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CowboyCoding), with its emphasis on artistry and hacking.

Downvote all you want... This is a simple truism, according to the definitions.

I **am not** saying that "Cowboy Coding" is the *best* methodoly for deliver software!

Comment: Eh, not sure I agree. For example, poetry has a form called a [Sonnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet) which has extremely strict rules. But, within those rules many poets have created great works.

Comment: You can also include haiku, flower arrangement, tea ceremony, etc.  There are "rules" of composition for painting, photography, etc.  These two are not mutually exclusive, and many times the greatest creativity comes from within the constraints of a structure.

Comment: To be clear, I not only disagree with your conclusion, but I think that it can hurt most software development teams more than it helps.  There are very few cowboys who are good and deliver, and in the chaos there will be showdowns at high noon when two cowboys disagree with each other.  Not very good for morale or creativity.

Comment: I edited.. I think you guys are applying the concept of constraints at the wrong level. And I didn't say that the outcome of CowboyCoding is, necessarily, GOOD. I simply pointed out the definitions of both creativity, and methodology... **they are incompatible at the level of definition**.

Comment: Ironically, you quote Ansel Adams who was one of the most methodical photographers.  He routinely tested his materials, and had a definite _process_ for making sure each frame he shot was going to work in the darkroom.  The arts that I listed also have a similar process surrounding them, a right and a wrong way to do them.  In short, the way you get there is just as important as the end result.

Comment: No, again you're flat-out wrong. Ansel Adams **transcended** the "traditional ideas, rules, patterns, relationships" (the definition of creativity). That's what made him unique. Now, photog students are taught to mimic his patterns.

Comment: I think we are talking across each other.  I think you are emphasizing too much the _first half_ of the definition you gave for creativity, and ignoring the second half: "to create meaningful new ideas, forms, methods, interpretations, etc.".  Bottom line is that there are ideas, forms, and _methods_ involved.  The same can be said of music.  You are talking to someone with more of an art background.  I know full well what goes into creative endeavors.

Comment: +1 - There's a huge difference between cowboy coding a prototype and a production application. Modern cars can be turbo charged, but I doubt they just bolted one on from a Formula I racer instead of engineering it in the context of the safety, cost and mass production requirements of commercial vehicles.

Comment: After seeing the edit, I still disagree.  I am focusing on the second half of the definition _you_ gave for creativity: "to create meaningful new ideas, forms, methods, interpretations, etc."  Essentially, any methodology built around the new ideas, forms, and methods will support creativity.  Ansel's zone system is a testament to that fact.  The zone system was (at the time) a new idea the helped _support_ his creativity.  The two definitions _can_ be mutually supportive.

Comment: Well, you are also talking to someone that was a paid musician before starting programming, but that's irrelevant... And sure there's methods involved. Even cowboy coders have their processes/methods.. A cowboy coder would be free, after all, to build a new cell phone by either taking the tradition approach with market research, focus groups, and project deliverables, or take the Apple approach and just go build something cool. I think it's obvious that the latter approach would allow for more **creativity**.

Comment: But Berin -- the key difference is that Adams was **free** to **create** that **new** methodology. Had he stuck with what was traditional techniques/methodologies at the time, we wouldn't have his prints today. Likewise, to take the iPhone example, if Apple had used a traditional methodologies, with customer-focused processes, we wouldn't have the iPhone. And again, a cowboy-coder does have techniques/processes... It's the truism of "if you choose not to choose, you've still made a choice".

Comment: I still think you are misreading the intent behind my comments.  I mean to say that creativity and methodology do not have to be mutually exclusive as you put forth.  Even within a company that supports "big process" there is room to tailor the process for your project's needs.  Additionally, software development is more like craftsmanship where several artisans (not artists) work together on the final product.  The artisans know how to work together, and are free to adjust their process as they create.  That is very different from cowboy coding.

Comment: I think this is just plain wrong. Creativity is not in inverse proportion to how strictly defined your framework of operation is. Given absolutely no boundaries, no framework, no process, no goal, no plan, no nothing, it is impossible to be creative. You have nothing to start from, nothing to give the spark. Good frameworks INCREASE the possibility for creative and efficient solutions. Using your logic, you'd be more creative if you didn't use a programming langue, more free if you didn't limit yourself to a CPU architecture, more free if you didn't communicate using natural language etc